# LibGDX CPU Rendering

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, render

We made a game which is not physics based and not resource heavy. In it's menu a simple animation is going and on some devices it's very slow. On devices with quad core cpus it runs well but with slower cpus for example dual core 1.2Ghz it's very slow.There is no calculations which can take cpu usage. We think that it is caused by cpu rendering because when we run the game with "Show GPU view updates"  option from developer options nothing highlights.

How to render with GPU in LibGDX or it is another problem?

Comment: What OS are we talking about here? And probably it's not a CPU rendering problem anyway. Show the code you are using to render please.

Comment: It's Android game and the apps resolution is  900x1600 if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

CPU rendering can vary in performance in large extent due to different levels of optimizations available and different architectures and instruction sets on different platforms.

Even then, if your game is not resource heavy, CPU rendering can be acceptable. If it is providing less performance than you need, **you should profile the code**.

That way you would know where optimization is actually required.

---

If profiling leads you to the conclusion that CPU rendering is the actual bottleneck, and you would like to migrate it to GPU, then LibGDX is the best way to go. It is adequately documented and there are many blogs, books that you may find resourceful.

[Blogs for 3D](http://blog.xoppa.com/basic-3d-using-libgdx-2/)

[Books references](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17879)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But really how can I render using GPU ?

Comment: If you use LibGDX for rendering, you will be using GPU. LibGDX abstrats it away. You just need to create some models (possibly meshes), create it's instances, create a camera, and put those instances to a batch. LibGDX will do everything including rendering. You won't need to write much code. Refer to the blog I mentioned above to see how to do this.

Comment: I am using all of that what you said but when running on the phone I think it is using CPU because on devices with low CPUs it is working very slow although there is no calculations or many objects .